# Select Grails Environment in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails, config

I've inherited a Grails project that is deployed in Tomcat. I essentially have to reverse engineer what the previous engineers have done.

My question is how does Grails *choose* among one of the Grails environments:

So in Config.groovy there is:

```
environments
{
    development 
    {
        .  . . 
    }
    production
    {
       . . .
    }    

}
```

But how in a deployed Tomcat server is say "development" chosen over "production" when starting up Tomcat?  I assumed it would be as some context or init parameter in web.xml, something like

```
<code>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>grails.environment</param-name>
        <param-value>production</param-value>
    </init-param>
</code>
```

All of the grails documentation presumes that you run

```
grails war your-selected-environment
```

but didn't design to document exactly how the war artifacts are affected.

Comment: But, how to check it Groovy/Grails Tool Suite?

Answer (score 10):

If you run

```
grails test war
```

for example, then the war is built so it will *only* use the code in the 'test' specific environment blocks. No need to worry about anything in the runtime environment.

The drawback is you have to build a separate war for each environment.

Alternately, you can just generate a single war and then set an environment variable in tomcat startup for each environment that tells grails what configurations to choose. You do this by setting, for example

```
-Dgrails.env=test
```

Comment: Right on, and here are some docs on this: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/Usage.html

Comment: But, how to check it Groovy/Grails Tool Suite?

Answer (score 5):

Edit your tomcat environment file. For Tomcat 7:

`/path/to/apache-tomcat-7.x.x/bin/setenv.sh`

and add the grails.env system property to the command line

`CATALINA_OPTS='-Xms2048m -Xmx8192m -Dgrails.env=dev';`
 *Replace dev with the environment you want*

Answer (score 0):

The environment is selected when you build the war, not when tomcat starts.  When you run

```
grails war
```

the `production` environment is implicitly selected, but you can override it on the command line with `-Dgrails.env=development`.  Check out the manual section on deployment: http://grails.org/doc/2.2.4/guide/single.html#deployingAnApplication

Comment: But that doesn't answer my question; tomcat is started with tomcat start scripts,not with grails war your-selected-environment;

Comment: The setting is stored in `application.properties` inside the war file.  It will contain e.g. `grails.env=production`.

Answer (score 0):

So you would say

```
    grails> prod war
```

where prod is the environment name. You could have an environment called space and do

```
    space war
```

I haven't seen documentation where you're able to change it after it's deployed. In my WEB-INF folder (of the exploded WAR) there is an application.properties file

```
grails.env=development
grails.war.deployed=true
grails.buildScope=war
app.servlet.version=2.5
```

I have my doubts that this will work but check it out.

Comment: But, how to check it Groovy/Grails Tool Suite?